# Windows batch-file, find a string between tag

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

i need to search within a file the first occurrence of a string.

I have this php file:

```
<?php

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
#
#  Gpl V2 and further license updates applies to this code
#
#  2015/05/21
#
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

error_reporting(0);

$version = '1.0 Alpha';

//some code
echo "\r\n===== ".$argv[0]." ".$version.": Select a channel =====: ";
```

I need to find this value 1.0 Alpha . In a bat file i have write this code.

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('findstr "$version" %~1') do (
set str=%%x
)
```

But he found all second string: echo "\r\n===== ".$argv[0]." ".$version.": Select a channel =====: ";

Solutions?

One last thing, the script could change from `$version = '1.0 Alpha';` to `$version = "1.0 Alpha";`

The quotes may change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to exit the loop after finding the first occurrence of the string. Try this:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%x in ('findstr "$version" %~1') do (
   set str=%%x
   goto :EndFor
)
:EndFor

set str=%str:"='% 
for /f "tokens=2 delims='" %%x in ('echo(%str%') do set str=%%x
echo(str=%str%
pause
```

Comment: Done, 1st problem solved :D thanks thanks thanks

Now, how i can grab only 1.0 Alpha ?
Considers that quotes may change from $version = '1.0 Alpha'; to $version = "1.0 Alpha";

I tried it with a replacement but the result is always "dirty"
set str=%str:$version =%

Comment: Check my edited answer... should do what you want for either format.

Comment: You've been very kind, works. I have to study the second piece of code you wrote: D
Thanks thanks thanks

Comment: Second piece replaces double quotes with single quotes so we are always dealing with same format. Second FOR loop extracts only 2nd token of string, using single quote as delimiter,

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in a single step, letting the FOR /F loop parse out the actual version string.

The odd syntax specifies `'` and `"` as token delimiters, and looks for the 2nd token.

```
@echo off
setlocal
for /f tokens^=2^ delims^='^" %%V in ('findstr $version "%~1"') do (
  set "version=%%V
  goto :break
)
:break
echo version=%version%
```